# Cannot find archive in Gmail even when looking in All Mail

Tags: gmail, gmail-archive

I seem to have tried everything suggested in answers to this same question.  Today, June 13th, 2019, I accidentally moved some messages into the archive, and I know I've done the same thing in the past. I cannot find anything called "archive" or any messages that are not labeled as in my "inbox."

Answer (score 1):

In Gmail, there is no Archive folder. All emails you "archive" ends up in All Mail folder - **https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all**

And to filter out non-archived emails you can search for **`in:archive`** - **https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#archive**

[image: 0]

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned, there is no "archive" folder in Gmail.

But I found a way to find only the messages sent to the "archive".

Write in the search bar:

```
has:nouserlabels -in:Sent -in:Chat -in:Draft -in:Inbox
```

In the search results you will see all the messages Which are not under any label  (="archive").